# Add samsung android device to eclipse

Tags: android

Please can you tell me how to connect samsung android device to eclipse for debugging.
I have downloads google usb driver in my sdk..

Comment: You need to setup your device to debug. Setting -> Apps -> Development and then Eclipse will find the debug/run device.

Comment: thanks, my problem is solved using samsung kies setup ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install Samsung Kies and you'll get required drivers, than setup device for development and finally debug in Eclipse.

Comment: +1 that was what i was doing. Does anybody know wether the samsung drivers are seperately available without kies?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the drivers for your phone and then set the phone in debug mode as suggested by the goodm in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in windows machine, download and install google usb drivers.

then, in your mobile phone, go to settings -> applications -> development and mark USB debugging and "allow mock locations"

also mark "unknown sources" in settings -> applications

Comment: Does this work on samsung phones, too? I didn-t succeed with the goolge driver but maybe i did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some drivers are available without Kies too with the Unified Android Toolkit.

The supported ones are the Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4, Nexus 5, Nexus 7 [2012], Nexus 7 [2013], Nexus 10, Samsung Galaxy S3, Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini, Samsung Galaxy S4, Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini, Samsung Galaxy S5, Samsung Galaxy Note 2, Samsung Galaxy Note 3, Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 [2012], Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 [2012], Samsung Galaxy Camera (smartcamera) and Samsung Galaxy Gear [smartwatch].

There is also a Basic Android Toolkit included which any Android device can use.